# Force applet to load only once

Tags: java, applet

Here's my situation:

I need to keep an applet loaded, and avoid having to reload it each time the user goes to the page where the applet is embedded.

How can i achieve this? Are there any parameters to set my applet to be singleton?
Here are the parameters I'm currently using:

```
<object id="mockapplet" name="mockapplet"
         classid="java:mockClass"
         type="application/x-java-applet"
         archive="#{myAppletPath}"
         height="1"
         width="1" codebase=".">
    <param name="code" value="mockApplet" />
    <param NAME="MAYSCRIPT" VALUE="true" />
    <param name="archive" value="#archivePath}" />
    <param name="JAVA_CODEBASE" value="." />
    <font color="red">Applet error</font>
</object>
```

in fact i need init() method to be call only once , in my case it is call each time my page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

well, if your applet is Embedded in your page, you reload it each time you reload the page ! if you want to keep parameters, you have to set a cookie.

Comment: that's not what i need , in fact i want to speed up the overall app performence by loading the applet only once .

Comment: then maybe you can use iframe or object to embed content and refresh it without reloading your applet ?

Comment: in fact i need init() method to be call only once , in my case it is call each time my page reloads.